# overriding equals method in subclass without definition of hashcode()

Tags: java, annotations, overriding, equals, hashcode

i have following code in my class:

```
public class Subclass<T> extends Superclass<T> {
//...

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj instanceof Subclass) {
        return str.equals(((Subclass<?>) obj).getStr());
    }
    if (obj instanceof Identity) {
        return str.equals(((Subclass<?>) obj).getStr());
    }
    return false;
}
}
```

my superclass:

```
 public class Superclass<T> {
 @NotNull
 String str;

 @Override
 public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj instanceof Identity) {
        return str.equals(((Identity<?>) obj).getStr());
    }
    return false;
 }

 @Override
 public int hashCode() {
    return str.hashCode();
 }
```

and checkstyle warns me `Definition of 'equals()' without corresponding definition of 'hashCode()'.` do i have to override `hashcode()` in my subclass even thou i dont need it anywhere or is there a better solution to get rid of this warning?

Comment: it´s not 100% necessary, but it´s still better to allways do so.The generell contract says, that if two objects are logical equal they should also produce the same hasCode. [see this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/what-issues-should-be-considered-when-overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java)

Comment: Do you know Lombok?

Comment: As long as you don't use the Subclass in any Hash-classes (``HashSet``, ``HashMap`` etc), you don't need it. Depends on how seriously you take the word 'contract'.

Comment: @DavidPérezCabrera yes, everthing is generated here with lombok however i need to override ``equals`` manually.

Comment: @f1sh its required from my code to not have any checkstyle warnings

Comment: @f1sh "As long as you don't use the Subclass in any Hash-classes..." and all of the classes you do use are contractually forbidden from using hash-based storage of those `Subclass` internally. You (almost certainly) can't know for definite that `Subclass` instances won't be put into hash-based storage now or at some time in the future; so it is a sensible defensive strategy to implement it now.

Comment: @AndyTurner thank you, this ensured me to implement it

Comment: @AkkaJaworek you should also make sure that `str` is `final` (along with any other fields you use to compute the hash code), because updates to those fields after insertion into a `HashMap` etc do not cause an update to the map. Basically, your instances can get "lost" in the map, in the sense that they will not necessarily be returned by `map.get`.

Comment: @AndyTurner completely correct. It just seems that this problem is happening on a very small scale.